# C++ overloading std::count_if() for a predicate and a value

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, overloading

Consider the code below, where the intention is to overload `std::count_if()` to work with a container as an argument instead of input and output iterators as usual.

```
// overload for call with predicate
template<typename Cont_T, typename Pred_T>
typename std::iterator_traits<typename Cont_T::iterator>::difference_type 
count_if(const Cont_T& c, Pred_T p) {
    return std::count_if(c.begin(), c.end(), p);
}

// overload for call with value
template<typename Cont_T, typename T = typename Cont_T::value_type>
typename std::iterator_traits<typename Cont_T::iterator>::difference_type
count_if(const Cont_T& c, const T& val) {
    return std::count_if(c.begin(), c.end(), val);
}

int main() {
   using namespace std;

   vector<int> v{1,2,3};
   count_if(v, 2);          // ambiguous call

   return 0;
}
```

The result is a compiler error that says the call is ambiguous.

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Standard library has `std::count` for values and `std::count_if` for predicates because otherwise it will be ambiguous (what if the container stores predicates?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using standard containers (with `value_type`<sup>1</sup>), you could try:

```
// overload for call with predicate
template<typename Cont_T>
typename std::iterator_traits<typename Cont_T::iterator>::difference_type 
count_if(const Cont_T& c, std::function<bool(typename Cont_T::value_type)> p) {
    return std::count_if(c.begin(), c.end(), p);
}

// overload for call with value
template<typename Cont_T>
typename std::iterator_traits<typename Cont_T::iterator>::difference_type
count_if(const Cont_T& c, const typename Cont_T::value_type& val) {
    return std::count(c.begin(), c.end(), val);
}
```

By forcing the type of the second parameter (not making it a template parameter), you avoid ambiguity. However, I would probably not do that and would stick to the standard version which is `count` / `count_if`.

<sub><sup>1</sup> If you cannot rely on `Cont_T::value_type`, you could replace it by a more "general" `decltype(*c.begin())`) or something alike.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

With some SFINAE, you may do

```
namespace helper
{

    using std::begin;
    using std::end;

    struct low_priority {};
    struct high_priority : low_priority {};

    template<typename Cont, typename Pred>
    decltype(true == std::declval<Pred>()(*begin(std::declval<const Cont&>())),
             void(), std::size_t{})
    count_if(const Cont& c, Pred&& p, high_priority)
    {
        return std::count_if(begin(c), end(c), std::forward<Pred>(p));
    }

    template<typename Cont, typename T>
    decltype(*begin(std::declval<const Cont&>()) == std::declval<T>(),
             void(), std::size_t{})
    count_if(const Cont& c, T&& val, low_priority) {
        return std::count(begin(c), end(c), std::forward<T>(val));
    }

}

template <typename Cont, typename T>
std::size_t count_if(const Cont& c, T&& val_or_pred)
{
    return helper::count_if(c, std::forward<T>(val_or_pred), helper::high_priority{});
}
```

As bonus, that also works for C-arrays.

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/15852956c78e423c)

Comment: It took me some time to digest your solution, but now that I understand(mostly) what is going on, I have a couple of questions if you have the time.

Comment: 1- I assume that all values before std::size_type are there, so that the unintended type for one function causes substitution failure, and consequently, that specialization does not contribute to the overload set, resulting in the other being called instead. But why do we have a void() in decltype?

Comment: 2- Why do we have a truth test for Pred version? Wouldn't there be a SF without it as well?

Comment: 3- Consider this alternative return type for Pred version `decltype(true == std::declval<Pred>()(*begin(Cont{}), void(), std::size_t{}))`. How is this inferior to using decltype() for constructing an object of type Cont as you suggest?

Comment: 4- Since the `count_if(const Cont& c, T&& val, low_priority)` version will **only** be called if val is **not** a predicate, why do we use a such return type construct for it, as if we are trying to generate a SF in calls **with** a predicate(which doesn't seem possible)? Why not simply use `std::size_type` as the return type for that version?

Comment: @Kermal: 1- `void()` is to handle evil classes with overloaded `operator ,`.

Comment: 3- That imposes that `Cont` is default-constructible.

Comment: 4- I try to be safe also about container of predicates or predicate which can be compared to container content (I think of container of `void*` with function pointer as predicate for example).

Answer (score -1):

Two mistakes: You are mixing up std::count() and std::count_if(), and you are using it wrong.

First, std::count_if() expects a predicate, not a value. The predicate is a function (or lambda expression) returning a boolean whether the argument should be counted. You want to put in a value, so you need to use std:count() instead.

Secondly, you cannot just pass the vector. Instead you need to pass a range specified by two iterators.

Please checkout this page for a working example of both std::count() and std::count_if():
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count

Comment: what do you mean he can't pass a vector? Surely he can

Comment: @sfk92fksdf well, they indeed couldn't pass vector to `std::count_if` just like Martin said. But of course, that's not a problem in OP's code, because they do not pass a vector to `std::count_if` but instead to `::count_if`.

Comment: errr... was there an edit of the original post? The code looks different now... In the OP the "using namespace std" should be removed, since this might actually create another ambiguity! Or better rename the function...

Comment: @MartinHierholzer : I made 2 edits in OP, but they were both before your anwser, which is exactly what I was looking for btw. But I don't see why `using namespace std;` would create an ambiguity.